# the current Workspace |ABC| does not contain a Project that matches the current setting of the Project: None

Tags: python-3.x, rally, pyral

Am trying to connect to Rally API through pyral, but am getting "the current Workspace |ABC| does not contain a Project that matches the current setting of the Project: None"

Here is my command :

`rally=Rally(server='rally1.rallydev.com', apikey="valid api key", workspace='MY-WORKSPACE', project='DT-CROWD')`

Am so sure and double checked that the project exists, in fact it was working when am using `pyral 1.1.1` with `python 3.5.2`

Currently am using python `3.5.2` and `pyral 1.2.0`

Please let me know, where am going wrong.

Comment: There is an open issue here: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForPython/issues/91

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use it with:

```
rally=Rally(server='rally1.rallydev.com', apikey="valid api key", workspace='MY-WORKSPACE', project='DT-CROWD', projectScopeDown=True)
```